# handle user-session-cookie and csrf token correctly for javascript app

Tags: xss, cookies, csrf

I have a django web app serving restful api endpoints and a javascript web app communicating with those endpoints through ajax.

They are under the same domain but in different ports.
server api ---- www.example.com:9000/api/endpoints
web app ---- www.example.com:9001

Now, we save two types of cookies.
user-session-cookie # authenticate the user. secure = True, http = True
csrftoken # secure = True

I wonder in general, is this implementation secure? In what circumstance the site is not secure?

I don't mark csrftoken http = True because the javascript app need get the csrftoken to send requests.  However, I am exposing the csrftoken to an XSS attack.  Is there anyway I can prevent csrftoekn from XSS attack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSS and CSRF have a rock/paper/scissors interaction.  XSS is always dominant over CSRF,  and almost all methods on the [CSRF Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) can be bypassed with XSS. A case where XSS and CSRF cannot be used to trigger a request is if the request requires the current password, a token texted or emailed to the user, or another value that cannot be obtained using a browser with the constraints of the SOP.  The [Sammy MySpace Worm](http://namb.la/popular/tech.html) is a good example of how a CSRF sync token can be undermined using an `XHMLHttpRequest()`.

XSS is a serious problem.  A strong method of defending against XSS is defining  a [Content-Security Policy](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/)(CSP) rule set that prevents injected HTML from executing JavaScript.  The CSP along with strong input validation can be used to prevent all XSS within an application with a high degree of certainty.